Showing a table that shows the Current, Latest and Wanted versions of each dependency
I have a task to update all packages specified in package.json in a project. I was able to update all, but I was asked to show proof that all packages are updated, a sort of table showing the Current, Latest, and Wanted version of each dependency. The "npm outdated" doesn't show anything since all the dependencies are up to date.
Thanks to everyone who will try to help!

"I was asked to show proof" - to whom? How is an empty output of npm outdated not sufficient to them? Talk to them what they expect.
